# Masking out row and column of 3-D numpy array based on 2-D boolean mask

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

For some 3-D cubic numpy array like the following:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]],[[19,20,21],[22,23,24],[25,26,27]]])

array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6],
        [ 7,  8,  9]],
       [[10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18]],
       [[19, 20, 21],
        [22, 23, 24],
        [25, 26, 27]]])
```

and some 2-D boolean mask array like the following:

```
b = np.array([[0,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,0]])

array([[0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0]])
```

I'm wondering if there is a way, using numpy operations, to compute a result such that for all elements where `b[i][j] = 0`, then `a[i,:,j] = 0` and `a[i,j,:] = 0`. It's guaranteed that `b` is `n x n` and `a` is `n x n x n`. In the above example the result would look like

```
array([[[ 0,  0,  0],
    [ 0,  5,  6],
    [ 0,  8,  9]],

   [[10, 11, 12],
    [13, 14, 15],
    [16, 17, 18]],

   [[19, 20,  0],
    [22, 23,  0],
    [ 0,  0,  0]]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [111]: b = np.array([[0,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,0]])

In [116]: I,J = np.nonzero(b==0)
In [117]: I,J
Out[117]: (array([0, 2]), array([0, 2]))
```

Test the indexing:

```
In [118]: a[I,:,J]
Out[118]: 
array([[ 1,  4,  7],
       [21, 24, 27]])
In [119]: a[I,J,:]
Out[119]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [25, 26, 27]])
```

Apply:

```
In [120]: a[I,:,J]=0
In [121]: a[I,J,:]=0
In [122]: a
Out[122]: 
array([[[ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  5,  6],
        [ 0,  8,  9]],

       [[10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18]],

       [[19, 20,  0],
        [22, 23,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0]]])
```